# Linux packet mark across network namespaces

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, network-namespaces

I am trying to use iptables to packet mark packets of a certain source/destination IP in the `mangle` table on a given host. The packets are later forwarded to a particular network namespace on the same host, yet the iptables rules that I've installed in that network namespace do not pick up on the mark. I am thus wondering: is packet marking only local to the network namespace the mark is being placed in? I was under the impression that since the mark is an "attribute" associated with the skb, that the kernel would keep track of the mark anywhere it's routed on the host, irrespective of the namespace.

Alternatively does anyone have any ideas of how to debug this? I installed a `TRACE` rule inside the network namespace I am targeting, but I am under the impression that I need to run `dmesg` to view the output and that doesn't make a lot of sense for a network namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is packet marking only local to the network namespace the mark is being placed in?

Yes. the mark is local to the network namespace. Each namespace has an independent network stack, so when a packet transits from one namespace to an other it's like transiting over the wire: no mark remains.

> I installed a TRACE rule inside the network namespace

It depends...

If using [`iptables-legacy`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-legacy.8)'s `TRACE` target the choices are limited:

- by default only the initial network namespace can log netfilter events to *dmesg*
- or with [`sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_log_all_netns=1`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/netfilter-sysctl.rst?h=v5.15#n10) then *all* network namespaces will log to *dmesg* which can be a problem when a lot of logs are generated by a lot of network namespaces

That's because *dmesg* is not per-namespace but global and sending logs to *dmesg* was initially the only available method for `TRACE`.

Now, if using *nftables*' [`nftrace`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#META_STATEMENT) statement or using [`iptables-nft`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-nft.8#DIFFERENCES_TO_LEGACY_IPTABLES), the previous method to send messages with the `TRACE` target is replaced by using the (netfilter) [netlink socket API](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/netlink.7#NETLINK_NETFILTER) which is namespace-aware and is sent only to listeners (ie: multicasting).

That means that when the *nft* variant like below:

```
# iptables-nft -V
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables)
```

but not the *legacy* variant like below:

```
# iptables-legacy -V
iptables v1.8.7 (legacy)
```

is used, then traces aren't sent to *dmesg* anymore but can be captured with `xtables-monitor --trace` instead. Again: `xtables-monitor` is intended only for the `iptables-nft` variant of `iptables`.

In this case one way to debug in parallel multiple network namespaces created by `ip netns add ...`, is to run multiple times in parallel [`xtables-monitor`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/xtables-monitor.8), once per network namespace, and write in separate logs or for example use [`ts`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/xtables-monitor.8) to tag every line of the output to have a timestamp and identify each namespace, making it easy to split the result later if needed.

Something like this for netns *foo* *bar* and *baz*:

```
for ns in foo bar baz; do
    ip netns exec "$ns" xtables-monitor --trace | ts -s "%.s $ns" &
done
```

( `pkill xtables-monitor` might be required later.)

With network namespaces not created through `ip netns add` one can replace `ip netns exec` with `nsenter` and more elbow grease usually involving information from the application that created them (`docker inspect`, `lxc-info` ...)

The command when using *nftables* is instead [`nft monitor trace`](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Ruleset_debug/tracing#monitoring_tracing_events) and behaves the same with regard to network namespaces. Actually `nft monitor trace` will also display traces created by *iptables-nft*'s `TRACE` target since it's the same API.